# YAML exception for powershell inline task - variables substitution doesn't work with nested variable

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I've got an issue if I am using PowerShell as an inline script with parameters in YAML for nested variables. For example,

```
steps:
- powershell: './src/script.ps1 -VAR1 $(VAR1.$(VAR2))'
  displayName: Build
```

Even if both variables are provided in build Variables, only `VAR1` and `VAR2` are replaced with value but the whole `$(Var1Value.VAR2Value)` variable is not.

If I used regular yaml syntax, it works:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Main
  inputs:
    scriptName: src/script.ps1
    arguments: '-VAR1 $(VAR1.$(VAR2))'
```

I don't want to use this syntax to be powershell version dependent. So I would prefer to use the first version. If somebody could help to point how to resolve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: I found that this is the problem if you are using Powershell@2 in Azure DevOps builds. This works with  Powershell@1.  Any idea why was it broken and  any work-around?

Comment: Hey Valeria, You mention that you are using an inline script, but then you are passing a `scriptname` for your task input, and not a `script`. Are you trying to pass a variable that was modified in another task to this task? I am not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish, could you add an example value for `VAR1` and `VAR2` build variables as well as the PARAM definition for your script.ps1?

Comment: Agree with @Brandon. Did you also set the variable for `VAR1.VAR2Value`? If not, how do you let the above script works? On my side, if I do not set this, all of them are compiled as `VAR1.VAR2Value`, and then prompt me `VAR1.VAR2Value` is not recognized. Could update more details on how do you configure the variable value, and your **ps1** file?

Comment: VAR1.VAR2 value is set in build variables as well as VAR1 and VA2. 
I found that problem is not with syntax but PowerShell version in YAML. It works perfectly with powershell@1 but not with powershell@2.
something is broken in newer version.

Comment: It's wired, since I tried the script on my side. All of them work fine. What I configure is `var1=123`,`var2=456`, `var1.456=789`. Both @1 and @2 are all work fine.